# what's the meaning of "tasking statement"? in intelligence settings

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "tasking statement"

> All intelligence studies start with some form of problem solving. In government intelligence groups, the problem may come in the form of a **tasking statement**.

Answer (score 1):

This term seems to me to be self-evident, both from the meanings of the words and from the context in which it is employed.

*Task*, as a verb, means to “impose a task upon”—*The subcommittee **was tasked** with nominating three candidates for the vacant seat.* A *tasking statement* is thus a statement which states (defines) a task imposed upon the person or persons to whom it is addressed.

And in this context, the task is imposed upon *government intelligence groups*, who are called upon to perform an *intelligence study* which will describe a solution to a particular problem.